# spreadsheet onEdit function: make it work for users not logged in

Tags: google-sheets

I want to auto-sort a google spreadsheet column automatically after the input is changed. I achieved that with the code below and it works.

**Question**: Is there a way to achieve that the code works for everyone accesssing the sheet (logged in and not logged in)?

Right now it just works for me when I am logged in. I am wondering about that, as I read that the function "onEdit" is a simple trigger, that does not require the authorisation of the user (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BJd8zRYD1qU)

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
    function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator")
  var range = sheet.getRange("I11:X142")

  // Sorts by the values in column 9
  range.sort({column: 9, ascending: false})

}
```

Comment: Simple triggers do not [request authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), not the same as does not need authorization. They still run under the alias/authorization of the user accessing the document. So, they will have to be logged in for the simple trigger to work under their authorization. You can use an [installed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) instead to run the same function under your authorization every time the sheet is edited. Make sure to change the name of the function.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an explanation how to do that step by step? Sry, but I am quite new to this.

Comment: Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for a step by step to install a trigger. And make sure to name your function anything but `onEdit()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm!

Comment: Awesome, could you answer your own question below, so others can benefit.