# Script always active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Sorry if this was asked before but I could not find then answer.

I created a spreadsheet that is used by many users. It has an onEdit script. However it only works for me. Does every single user has to accept access for the script to change the spreadsheet?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a [mcve] and a brief description of your search/research effort as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114242/spreadsheet-onedit-function-make-it-work-for-users-not-logged-in

Comment: Take a look on [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), this will clarify your doubts.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I tried siply to create a public link and open it without any google log-in, and the script wouldn´t work

Answer (score 0):

The script will be run by and have the permissions of the owner that created the trigger to the script.

Ie if your account created the simple or installable trigger and steve opens the sheet, his actions will trigger the script to be run by your account.

None clear behavior that I have noticed that might explain what you are seeing:
- if lets say bob only has read only access or comment only access to the spread sheet no triggers will fire for his instance ( ie onopen() ).

Feel free to attach your full or a snippet of your code and trigger settings and someone should be able to assist in debugging.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I tried siply to create a public link and open it without any google log-in, and the script wouldn´t work

Comment: @MarioCH Do they have anonymous  edit access? If they can view only I wouldn't expect it to run at all. I have a feeling that if there is no google login to attach the action too having none of the triggers run is expected behavior.